# AES-128-ECB - Inconsistent encryption result of node js and java

Tags: node.js, encryption

node js code：

```
function AES_encrypt(){

  var bKey = new Buffer('24Qn9974h50D9DNi', 'utf-8');

  var bInput = new Buffer(‘test’, 'utf-8');

  console.log(bKey.length);

  var cipher = crypto.createCipher('AES-128-ECB',bKey);

  //cipher.setAutoPadding(auto_padding=false);

  var crypted = cipher.update(bInput,null,'base64');

  crypted+=cipher.final('base64');

  console.log(crypted);

  return crypted;
}
```

get Result：57b6b7oulw7eO5h7efZ9/w==

java code：

main java：

```
String data = AES.encryptToBase64("test","24Qn9974h50D9DNi");
```

AES java：

```
public static String encryptToBase64(String data, String key){
    try {
        byte[] valueByte = encrypt(data.getBytes("utf-8"), key.getBytes("utf-8");
        return new String(Base64.encode(valueByte));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("encrypt fail!", e);
    }

}

 public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] data, byte[] key) {

    if(key.length!=16){
        throw new RuntimeException("Invalid AES key length (must be 16 bytes)");
    }
    try {
        SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES"); 
        byte[] enCodeFormat = secretKey.getEncoded();
        SecretKeySpec seckey = new SecretKeySpec(enCodeFormat,"AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, seckey);// 初始化
        byte[] result = cipher.doFinal(data);
        return result; // 加密
    } catch (Exception e){
        throw new RuntimeException("encrypt fail!", e);
    }
}
```

get Result：wA1JU6VxMaVl8Ck8pBrX8A==

Comment: Didn't actually look at it much, but something to remember is that node automatically pads your encryption things for you.

http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_cipher_setautopadding_auto_padding_true

Comment: Thank you for your reply! java complement bit node is not, this is my obsession

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use crypto.createCipheriv to solve the issue,
  http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createcipheriv_algorithm_key_iv

Answer (score 0):

You need to pad the string `"test"` to 16 bytes. I believe Java uses PKCS padding by default (but there are other padding schemes, too).

```
String data = AES.encryptToBase64("test","24Qn9974h50D9DNi");
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I need to java encryption result as the goal to achieve with node js, there are other ways?